# Variable scope within a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have noticed in mysql that why preparing a dynamic query it requires what I think is a global variable.  Is there a way to limit the scope of the variable to only betwenn the begin and end statements?  Below is my test script when returns a value of 10 for the limitCnt variable.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists testProc//
create procedure testProc ()
begin
--  DECLARE limitCnt INT default 10;
  SET @limitCnt = 10;

  PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM `participants` LIMIT ?';
  EXECUTE stmt USING @limitCnt; -- the using part of the execute does not like the local variable

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
end//
call testProc()//
select @limitCnt//

drop procedure testProc//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use local variables then they have to be scoped within `begin...end` block, however if you have nested `begin` and `end` blocks within some `begin` and `end` block then the variables declared in the "so called" parent `begin` and `end` block are accessible from the "so called" children `begin` and `end` blocks.  Please read through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html.

What you are doing in your code is setting a session variable called `limitCnt` which is accessible and available anywhere in your procedure hence you are getting `10` as result when you do `select @limitCnt`.

To use a local variable use `declare var_name var_type` within your `begin...end` block.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around it. It's by design in MySql.

Local/stored procedure/stored function level variables

1. can't be used to `PREPARE` a statement from
2. can't be referred in you prepared statement
3. can't be used to pass a parameter value to `EXECUTE` with `USING`

> **[PREPARE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/prepare.html)**
>   ... Statement names are not case sensitive. preparable_stmt is either a
>   string literal or **a user variable** that contains the text of the SQL
>   statement. ...
>
> ... A statement prepared in stored program context **cannot refer to stored
>   procedure or function parameters or local variables** because they go
>   out of scope when the program ends and would be unavailable were the
>   statement to be executed later outside the program. ...
>
> **[EXECUTE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execute.html)**
>   ...
>   Parameter values can be supplied **only by user variables**, and the USING
>   clause must name exactly as many variables as the number of parameter
>   markers in the statement. ...

User variables have a scope of a session.

Now, to address your concern just always explicitly set a value to a user defined variable before you use it. Just as you did assigning a default value to `@limitCnt`.

```
SET @limitCnt = 10;
```

Also you can set a value of `NULL` to such variable at the end of your stored procedure/stored function/script.

```
SET @limitCnt = NULL;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab209/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL 5.0 Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execute.html), you cannot use local variables in `EXECUTE ... USING` statements. See an excerpt from the documentation below on how to use the statement:

```
EXECUTE stmt_name
[USING @var_name [, @var_name] ...]
```

You have to use the @ prefix.